# How to restore PostgreSQL database from .tar file?

Tags: postgresql

I have all PostgreSQL databases backed up during incremental backups using WHM, which creates a $dbName.**tar** file.

Data is stored in these .tar files, but I do not know how to restore it back into the individual databases via SSH.  In particular the file location.

I have been using:

```
pg_restore -d client03 /backup/cpbackup/daily/client03/psql/client03.tar
```

which generates the error 'could not open input file: Permission denied'

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Does the user you're running this command with has access to that file ?

Comment: Hi Mat, you would think so, (running as root) but have just solved the issue after many many combinations, and moving the raw .tar file to tmp....

pg_restore -c -i -U postgres -d client03 -v "/tmp/client03.tar" -W

The -W at the end was the main trick which forced the password input as required which enabled everything to be put back together.

Answer (score 43):

Found the correct string of code, in case someone else finds this thread.

```
pg_restore -c -U postgres -d client03 -v "/tmp/client03.tar" -W
```

The break down was from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/app-pgrestore.html and a bit of trial and error.

Essentially...

```
-c to clean the database
-U to force a user
-d to select the database
-v verbose mode, don't know why
"$$" the location of the files to import in tmp to get around permission issues
-W to force asking for the password to the user (postgres)
```

Hope the above assists someone else.

Comment: how do same with tar.gz ?

Comment: This did work for me but it seems like the -i and -W did not work anymore and had to be removed. resulting in: pg_restore -c -U postgres -d databaseName -v "/tmp/client03.tar"

Answer (score 3):

When using PgAdmin III to do the restore for me, it worked flawlessly by using the following command which it constructed itself:

```
pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username "my_user_name" --dbname "my_db_name" --role "my_user_name" --no-password  --verbose "/Users/me/Desktop/backup_file.tar"
```

Note to avoid warnings it's a good idea to have the role of the owner of objects in the backup file already existing in the target server. Also you should already have the target DB created and owned by that role.

Answer (score 1):

For version 9.5, run the following in command line

`pg_restore -W -c -U [username] -d [database_name] -v "[path to extracted tar]"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain it can import a .tar file. I would do a

```
tar -zxvf client03.tar
```

to extract whatever was inside the file, and try pg_restore again. I know pg_restore works, as we have the same restore method from bare metal restores.

Comment: Hi Stephen, yes apparently it can, it just took me a while to get the correct code, and to drop the file into a folder with permission to be accessed :)

Comment: The "-z" would return an error, as it is just a tar, not compressed with gzip.

Comment: Alex is 100% correct.

Comment: I use `unp` which does unpackung always right

Answer (score 0):

Below was generated for me from pgAdmin iii by clicking on the database and right clicking and 
selecting restore.  I navigated to the .tar file I had and it did it on its own.

```
/usr/bin/pg_restore --host localhost --port 5434 --username "postgres" \
--dbname "dvdrental" --no-password  --schema public --verbose \
"/home/npena/Desktop/dvd/dvdrental.tar"
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU/LINUX CONSOLE:

> pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U "postgres" -d "dvdrental_tpl" -v 
>   "/var/backups/dvdrental.tar";

-- Detail Help

> pg_restore --help